# Flip UIImage Along Either Axis

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm trying to create a method which flips a UIImage along the X axis, Y axis, or both. I keep getting close but my transform knowledge isn't good enough to get all the way there. Here is the code I have so far:

```
- (UIImage *)flippedImageByAxis:(MVImageFlip)axis{
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGAffineTransform verticalFlip = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.size.height);
     CGAffineTransform horizFlip = CGAffineTransformMake(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, self.size.width, 0.0);

     if(axis == MVImageFlipXAxis || axis == MVImageFlipXAxisAndYAxis)
         CGContextConcatCTM(context, horizFlip);
     if(axis == MVImageFlipYAxis || axis == MVImageFlipXAxisAndYAxis)
         CGContextConcatCTM(context, verticalFlip);

     CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

     UIImage *flipedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     return flipedImage;
 }
```

This flips the image but not properly. The Y-flipped image doesn't get flipped at all, the X flipped image looks like the XY image should look like, and the XY image looks like what the Y image should look like. Combining the transforms and getting them to work properly is making my head hurt.

The MVImageFlip enum is just the three you see in the code. Nothing special.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I finally was able to figure this out. Here is the code that works for anyone else who might need it.

```
- (UIImage *)flippedImageByAxis:(MVImageFlip)axis{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if(axis == MVImageFlipXAxis){
        // Do nothing, X is flipped normally in a Core Graphics Context
    } else if(axis == MVImageFlipYAxis){
        // fix X axis
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        // then flip Y axis
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.size.width, 0);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    } else if(axis == MVImageFlipXAxisAndYAxis){
        // just flip Y
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.size.width, 0);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

    UIImage *flipedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return flipedImage;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer image scale in context like this: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);`

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

```
UIImage* myimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myimage.png"];
myimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: myimage.CGImage scale: 1.0f orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

Comment: I actually found this snippet before and tried it first. It didn't do anything, the resulting UIImages were exactly the same as the input. I'll try it one more time to be sure.

Comment: Just tried it again, still doesn't do anything. Very strange.

Comment: The correct parameter is `UIImageOrientationDownMirrored` or `UIImageOrientationDown` to flip the image on its head. Documentation: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIImageOrientationUpMirrored)

Answer (score 7):

If you're intending to just display the image and not save it, you probably don't want to create a second CGContext.  It's far more efficient to just use the already-loaded CGImage in the UIImage, and change the orientation like so:

```
- (UIImage *)flippedImageByFlippingAlongXAxis:(BOOL)flipOnX andAlongYAxis:(BOOL)flipOnY
{
    UIImageOrientation currentOrientation = self.imageOrientation;
    UIImageOrientation newOrientation = currentOrientation;

    if (flipOnX == YES) {
        switch (newOrientation) {
            case UIImageOrientationUp:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationUpMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationDown:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationDown;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationLeft:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationRight:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationRightMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeft;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (flipOnY == YES) {
        switch (newOrientation) {
            case UIImageOrientationUp:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationDownMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationDown:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationUpMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationDown;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationLeft:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationRightMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationRight:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;
                break;
            case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
                newOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeft;
                break;
        }
    }

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage scale:self.scale orientation:newOrientation];
}
```

When you start a new CGContext and doing flip using CGContextDrawImage, you're allocating another block of memory to hold the same bytes in a different order.  By changing the UIImage orientation, you're able to avoid another allocation.  The same image data is used, just drawn in a different orientation.

Comment: This is old but I thought I would comment. I actually did need to save the images in my specific issue. This is good advice either way, and is more efficient if the image is only destined for display.

Comment: I like this answer, and I like reusing the CGContext as I'm only displaying the picture. As or right now it is incorrect however. Changing (in Swift notation) `.Up` to `.Down` or `.LeftMirrored` to `.RightMirrored` is actually doing a 180 degree rotation, so 4 cases in each switch is not doing a reflection. To fix it in the example above, you just have to make sure that, for each case, you are always adding or removing 'Mirrored'. I'll add another answer in swift for completeness

Comment: Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is merely a slightly fixed and 'updated to Swift' version of the old answer by @ultramiraculous. Just in case it helps someone.

Vertical Flip (reflection over x-axis):

```
func flipV(im:UIImage)->UIImage {
    var newOrient:UIImageOrientation
    switch im.imageOrientation {
    case .Up:
        newOrient = .DownMirrored
    case .UpMirrored:
        newOrient = .Down
    case .Down:
        newOrient = .UpMirrored
    case .DownMirrored:
        newOrient = .Up
    case .Left:
        newOrient = .LeftMirrored
    case .LeftMirrored:
        newOrient = .Left
    case .Right:
        newOrient = .RightMirrored
    case .RightMirrored:
        newOrient = .Right
    }
    return UIImage(CGImage: im.CGImage, scale: im.scale, orientation: newOrient)
}
```

Horizontal Flip (reflection over y-axis)

```
func flipH(im:UIImage)->UIImage {
    var newOrient:UIImageOrientation
    switch im.imageOrientation {
    case .Up:
        newOrient = .UpMirrored
    case .UpMirrored:
        newOrient = .Up
    case .Down:
        newOrient = .DownMirrored
    case .DownMirrored:
        newOrient = .Down
    case .Left:
        newOrient = .RightMirrored
    case .LeftMirrored:
        newOrient = .Right
    case .Right:
        newOrient = .LeftMirrored
    case .RightMirrored:
        newOrient = .Left
    }
    return UIImage(CGImage: im.CGImage, scale: im.scale, orientation: newOrient)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version:

```
func flipV(im:UIImage)->UIImage {
        var newOrient:UIImageOrientation
        switch im.imageOrientation {
        case .up:
            newOrient = .downMirrored
        case .upMirrored:
            newOrient = .down
        case .down:
            newOrient = .upMirrored
        case .downMirrored:
            newOrient = .up
        case .left:
            newOrient = .leftMirrored
        case .leftMirrored:
            newOrient = .left
        case .right:
            newOrient = .rightMirrored
        case .rightMirrored:
            newOrient = .right
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: im.cgImage!, scale: im.scale, orientation: newOrient)
    }

    func flipH(im:UIImage)->UIImage {
        var newOrient:UIImageOrientation
        switch im.imageOrientation {
        case .up:
            newOrient = .upMirrored
        case .upMirrored:
            newOrient = .up
        case .down:
            newOrient = .downMirrored
        case .downMirrored:
            newOrient = .down
        case .left:
            newOrient = .rightMirrored
        case .leftMirrored:
            newOrient = .right
        case .right:
            newOrient = .leftMirrored
        case .rightMirrored:
            newOrient = .left
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: im.cgImage!, scale: im.scale, orientation: newOrient)
    }
```

Comment: Please don't provide code-only answers. You should elaborate your approach. This helps other users to understand your solution better.